# mysql processes still alive from processlist

Tags: mysql, process, timeout

I have this in my my.cnf

```
wait_timeout=1800
interactive_timeout=1800;
net_read_timeout=1800;
net_write_timeout=1800
```

but when i execute

```
show processlist;
```

I have processes that still running more than 4500sec even they are in 'Sleep' command.

please help about this, thank you.

Comment: Have you restarted your mysql server having these variables `wait_timeout=1800
interactive_timeout=1800;
net_read_timeout=1800;
net_write_timeout=1800` ?

Comment: yes, i did. if execute show variables like '%timeout%', it will show the settings i entered.

Answer (score 0):

Does `PROCESSLIST` show `4500` in the Time column?  Or did you get that number from elsewhere?

Is the process something special, such as the replication thread?

Did the process do `SET SESSION wait_timeout=...` to avoid being timed out?  From outside, you cannot detect if this happened.

Comment: yes the 4500 is from the time column and it increment by 1 per second.

Comment: yes the 4500 is from the time column and it increment by 1 per second, and the process is not a replication.  the process was created by the windows  application, after finish executing the query it just stay there, and i did not do set SESSION wait_timeout. my only hint is that the thread process was in the connection pool, but the app is already idle for very long time. so mysql should kill the process. please help me thanks.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know if "mysql_ping" would keep it awake without resetting the Time.  "kill" (from within mysql) would work.  But is it causing trouble?  If the `PROCESSLIST` is filled with `max_connections` processes that are not dying, that is a problem -- new connections will be denied.

Comment: ohhh, i am using "mysql_ping" before i execute the query, i will try to remove it

Comment: i tried ti remove "mysql_ping" but still no avail. any more suggestion, please.